# Api Cielo: Erro ao criar uma compra

Tags: api, postman

Quando envio uma requisição simulando uma compra:

**URL**
https://apisandbox.cieloecommerce.cielo.com.br/1/sales

**Json**

```
{
   "MerchantOrderId":"2014111703",
   "Customer":{
      "Name":"Comprador crédito simples"
   },
   "Payment":{
     "Type":"CreditCard",
     "Amount":15700,
     "Installments":1,
     "SoftDescriptor":"123456789ABCD",
     "CreditCard":{
         "CardNumber":"1234123412341231",
         "Holder":"Teste Holder",
         "ExpirationDate":"12/2030",
         "SecurityCode":"123",
         "Brand":"Visa"
     }
   }
}
```

**Resposta:**
Status erro: 500 Internal Server Error

**Imagem**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

O erro esta no tipo de envio
Não pode ser **Text** tem de set **Json**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]